# C# NRE when selecting a subelement by relative XPath with XPathSelectElement

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm using System.Xml.XPath when I try to extract data from an XML document.
Here's a XML fragment:

```
[skip]
<wb:Content>
  <wb:Position>
    <wb:Product>
      <pref:UnitType>Packed</pref:UnitType>
      <pref:Type>АП</pref:Type>
      <pref:FullName>xxxxxxxxxxx</pref:FullName>
      <pref:ShortName>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</pref:ShortName>
      <pref:AlcCode>xxxxxx</pref:AlcCode>
      <pref:Capacity>1</pref:Capacity>
      <pref:AlcVolume>12</pref:AlcVolume>
```

First I try to select a wb:Position XElement using:

```
/// mgr is a namespace manager
IEnumerable<XElement> positions = 
  doc.XPathSelectElements("/ns:Documents/ns:Document/ns:WayBill_v3/wb:Content/wb:Position/wb:Product", mgr);
```

This works fine. Next, I iterate through all the found elements:

```
foreach (XElement xposition in positions)
{
    string name =   
     xposition.XPathSelectElement("wb:Product/pref:FullName", mgr).Value;
 ...
}
```

And this gives me a NRE because XPathSelectElement always returns null.
I checked and double-checked the XPath and I'm absolutely sure it is correct.
Apparently the XPathSelectElement extension doesn't understand relative XPaths or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: _"I checked and double-checked the XPath and I'm absolutely sure it is correct"_ - I'm not, you have `wb:Product` twice. Once at the end of the first `XPathSelectElements()`, and one at the start of the second.

Comment: Oops! You're my saviour. I was thinking I was going mad with this thing. Thankyouthankyouthankyou!